# How am I supposed to show the data when admin approve in my view

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, I am creating candidates approval/rejected. Now I am working for the approval. I have "general.blade.php" where this is showing all the pending list. Then when the admin approve selected candidates, it will pass the data to the new blade I called "Approved.blade.php". However, in my case. when I click one candidate, It pass all the candidate list to the new blade, either pending or approve.

**CandidateController.php**

```
public function postApprove($id)
 {
    $candidates = GeneralForm::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
    if($candidates)
    {
        $candidates->status = 1;
        $candidates->save();
        $candidates=GeneralForm::where('status' , '1')->get();
        $menu = Menu::get();
        $current_menu = 2;
        $candidates = GeneralForm::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('approve', compact('candidates', 'menu', 'current_menu'));}
```

**general.blade.php**
*This is my button where admin can approve candidate *

```
 <a class="flex items-center " href="{{route('application',['id'=>$candidate->id])}}"> <i data-feather="user-check" class="w-4 h-4 mr-1"></i> Accept </a>
```

I am supposed to show only approve candidates here
**approve.blade.php**

```
        <tbody>@foreach ($candidates as $candidate)
            <tr class="intro-x">
                <td class="w-40">
                    <div class="font-medium whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $candidate->fullname }}</div> 
                </td>
                <td class="w-40">
                    <div class="font-medium whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $candidate->email }}</div> 
                </td> </tbody>@endforeach
```

**route**

```
Route::get('application/approve/{id}', 'CandidateController@postApprove')->name('application');
```

What I am getting is, whenever I click one candidate, it will redirect me into approval.blade.php. however it is showing me whole list including the pending. I want it to show only the approve candidate. My database data working fine, only my view is not. Can someone help me which part is wrong?

Comment: Just realized the shown code is already the one used to show one candidate. `GeneralForm::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();` can be shortened to `GeneralForm::find($id)`. If you only want _one_ candidate I also suggest using `$candidate` instead of the plural `$candidates`.  `$candidates = GeneralForm::latest()->paginate(5);` will get you 5 items, not sure why that is in there since you only want one.

Comment: thank you sooo muchh!! yes $candidates = GeneralForm::latest()->paginate(5); is the one get me wrong @brombeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting 5 candidates using `$candidates = GeneralForm::latest()->paginate(5);` and passing that data to your view. Since you only need one candidate, you should update your code as follows:

```
public function postApprove($id)
{
    $candidate = GeneralForm::find($id);
    $candidate->status = 1;
    $candidate->save();
    $menu = Menu::get();
    $current_menu = 2;
 
    return view('approve', compact('candidate', 'menu', 'current_menu'));
}
```

- `GeneralForm::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();` can be shortened to `GeneralForm::find($id)`
- Removed the line `$candidates=GeneralForm::where('status' , '1')->get();` since that would get you a list of candidates, and it would be overwritten by `$candidates = GeneralForm::latest()->paginate(5);` anyway.
- Renamed `$candidates` to `$candidate` to reflect that there's only one item

Then in your view you can get rid of the `@foreach...` since we only have one item to display:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="intro-x">
    <td class="w-40">
      <div class="font-medium whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $candidate->fullname }}</div> 
    </td>
    <td class="w-40">
      <div class="font-medium whitespace-no-wrap">{{ $candidate->email }}</div> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

- Removed the `@foreach` since we only have one item to display

Comment: I have one more issue that I overlooked just now. when admin click the approve button, it will show the **approve.blade.php** with one candidate (which is correct). But when I tried to click on my side-nav where my **approve.blade.php** it again showing all candidates. Is it something wrong with my menu database?

Comment: I have no clue what your sidebar contains and why that fails, needs a little more info. Do you have a list of candidates in your sidebar aswell?

Comment: I got it, it has something to do with my controller. I forgot to change the database code which showing the approved one. My bad and sorry!

Comment: Not a problem ;)